# What files do you check-in to source countrol management system when working in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, version-control

We have a main web application that references several other projects. Do you check-in .csproj/.sln files into source control? If so, do you use these files for msbuild or do you just include *.cs to build your dll? Does ILMerge help in any way with performance?

Comment: Looking for some best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should aim to check in everything that is needed so that someone can take a fresh install of Visual Studio, do a checkout, double-click the .sln file, build and be on their way.

.sln and .csproj are a no-brainer, in my opinion: what happens if you add a new file to the project: everybody would have to manually add the file to their project files if you didn't commit the .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

- ILMerge - no. Not for web applications. Not for the rest either.
- Checkin? What about letting visual studio handle it. Now, in general - source control without all relevant files is garbage ;) So, it should include stuff like the project and solution.